# Flutter Image Picker doesn't pick image from Album/Gallery

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-image

I'm trying to implement imagepicker library in my app. My app runs without any errors but I can't pick/select images from the album/gallery. On selecting the image the app should display the image in the body but nothing happens. I have to tap on Cancel to go back to the main screen. I should also mention that the console returns `null` for the print statement `print('image: $image');`

Kindly help.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
File image;
final picker = ImagePicker();

  Future getImage() async {
    final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    setState(() {
      if (pickedFile != null) {
        image = File(pickedFile.path);
      } else {
        print('image: $image');
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Image Picker'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: image == null
            ? Text('No image selected.')
            : Image.file(image),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: getImage,
        tooltip: 'Pick Image',
        child: Icon(Icons.add_a_photo),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below code

```
   Future getImage() async {
        File pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
            if (pickedFile != null) {
                setState(() {
                    image = File(pickedFile.path);
                });
             } else {
                 print('image: $image');
             }
    }
```

Comment: I tried your code but the problem still persists.

Comment: I changed the type to File as you suggested which showed and error *A value of type 'PickedFile' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'File'*. I changed to type to PickedFile as suggested by the Editor which got rid of the error so the new code is `PickedFile pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);`. But the main problem is still there.

Comment: This is a known issue for those running on M1 MacBook. I'll try running on a physical device. Thanks. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/71943